# Getting Data from Core Data with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I can't seem to get this right. I want to get core data from my Database and display all in table view. Running this only displays the last ID multiple times on my table. Could someone advise what I'm doing wrong and/or possibly assist? Thanks.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension MyFavourites {

@NSManaged var id: String?

}
```

-

```
var myFavs : [MyFavourites]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyFavourites")
    freq.returnsObjectsAsFaults  = false

    do {
        myFavs = try context.executeFetchRequest(freq) as? [MyFavourites]
    } catch _ {
        myFavs = nil
    }

    tableView.reloadData()


}
```

-

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return (myFavs?.count)!
}
```

-

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if myFavs!.count > 0 {

        for result: AnyObject in myFavs! {

            if let favID: String = result.valueForKey("id") as? String {

                cell.textLabel?.text = favID                    
            }
        }
            } else {
        print("No Record")
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your code correctly, it will display last recorded favId in all cells. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` asks you for value for current cell, but instead of providing that, you loop through all of them and repeatedly assign the same label with favID rewriting it multiple times. At the end of the cycle the label will have the last ID from the list.

You need to remove the loop and assign `cell.label.text` with ID value from `myFavs[indexPath.row]`.

Comment: I did `cell.textLabel?.text = myFavs[indexPath.row]` and got the error  `Cannot subscript a value of type '[MyFavourites]?'`

Comment: You need to get the ID out of the object and assign that. The same way you did it with the `result`.